# Entity Framework SaveChanges does not save data

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, sql-server-ce

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{
    var dbUser = (from u in db.Users
                  where u.Id == Id
                  select u).First();

    dbUser.LastName = LastName;
    dbUser.FirstName = FirstName;
    dbUser.GroupId  = GroupId;
    dbUser.VoicesCount = VoicesCount;

    db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

This does not save any changes to the database. But there are no exceptions, either. Why?

UPD: Ok, I tried it also for SQL Server CE and nothing changes. It doesn't save the changed data.

Comment: have you tried to use profiler and see if there is actual query being executed on savechanges ?

Comment: It's difficult to do. I use sqllite.

Comment: @marc_s it's changed. I google this issue and notice, that users has problems with SQL CE and EF. I try to connect to SQL SERVER and it works PERFECT. So problem is in sql ce provider or something else.
It not code problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look in you bin/debug folder for a copy of the database, it will have the changed data, as you are including the database a content with your app

Comment: I wish i can upvote you twice. I am pulling my hairs why it is not getting the records after i load the application again.